Updating legacy Flutter projects for Android 14 (API 34) compatibility
I need to update 4 flutter project that was written by another developer. Due to the android play store targetSdkVersion policy thing that is going on I have to change target 34.
My problem is that I use an M1 mac book and the project were written between 2021 and 2022 so they are fairly old and there was no upgrade since projects were written. Meaning of no dependency upgrades and migrations were done. I will surely need to do that as well, but for now I have to make them build for sdk 34 ASAP. But on M1 mac I keep running into hundreds of errors... :video_player missing I added it the pubspec still, then JAVA version problem etc.. I am struggling with it for days if not weeks...
What can I do easily and quickly so the project builds the apk with the increased targetSdkVersion?

what sdk constraints do they have?

@pskink
environment:
sdk: ">=2.19.2 <3.0.0"
and I also have:
environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

so it should not be much problem then... i thought that i t was <2.0.0 version.... does it  use any dependencies that are not supported anymore?
